# Android Options Menu not receiving focus

Tags: android, android-menu, android-keypad

On a device with hardware Menu key, on pressing the Menu Key the Options Menu is inflated but the items are not receiving focus to navigate.I have confirmed the Activity window looses focus on Menu Keypress using the onWindowFocusChangedListener. Any Ideas on how to debug focus for a Menu window or why the Menu is not receiving focus.